# Highlight Taxonomy menu on frontend when custom post type is displayed in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-4, underscores-wp

I created a taxonomy Portfolio and custom post type Project. Portfolio is like category for project so when adding a project user can select under which portfolio is should be shown.

On the frontend there is a menu item Portfolio in main menu. Clicking on it shows portfolio archive page with all its projects and portfolio menu item is highlighted in main menu.

When user clicks on a project in portfolio archive page user is redirected to project page where all the details of that project are shown.

I want portfolio menu item to be highlighted in main menu when user is viewing project. How can we do this?